# using drupal and bootstrap subtheme - jquery not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have the bootstrap theme (using a subtheme) and have included my own scripts.js file (from my .info) when I enter code such as alert("hello"); then it works fine. But nothing happens when I try $('#edit-profile-teacher').hide();

There are no errors in the console and I have no idea why something so basic is not working.

I am using jquery update module and have it set to 1.7

Cheers,
Garry.

Comment: check whether you put jquery twice... must be a conflict

Answer (score 1):

You should provide all JS code by extending the Drupal behaviors; like so:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MyCustomTheme = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Do anything you want here.
      $('#some-selector').hide();

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

While other approaches will work (e.g. just adding on document load), this is the proper way of adding JS in Drupal themes.

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap jquery in this for it to work in drupal.

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your stuff here
    alert('what up?!');
    $('#edit-profile-teacher').hide();
});
}(jQuery));
```